# Operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

1. According to the [Quantum Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulations_of_quantum_mechanics), can we write  $\langle q|p\rangle  = e^{ipq}$?
2. If so then how?
3. And if we transfer to integrate formulation then how it will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this notation is very common. Consider q and p as quantum numbers designating eigenstates of coordinate and positional operators. The integral representation reads:
$$\langle q|p\rangle  = \int d \mathbf{q}' \delta(\mathbf{q}-\mathbf{q}') e^{i\mathbf{p} \mathbf{q}'}$$

Comment: Just one important formal remark: Note, that $|q \rangle$ and $|p \rangle$ are so-called generalized eigenstates of position and momentum operator respectively, which means that they are not elements of a Hilbert space (i.e. aren't square-integrable). However, they have a rigorous mathematical meaning in the sense of Gelfand triples, so this fact doesn't make any problems in calculations.